# What is the difference between EnterUpgradeableReadLock and TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock?

Tags: .net, multithreading, locking

What is the difference between System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.EnterUpgradeableReadLock  and System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock? in .NET?  Is it just the timeout option?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EnterUpgradeableReadLock` always blocks until the lock is obtained.  `TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock` returns false if the lock cannot be obtained in the specified time.  If you use this, you have to be prepared to handle the case where you don't get the lock.

From the docs for [EnterUpgradeableReadLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterupgradeablereadlock.aspx):

> This method blocks until the calling
>   thread enters the lock, and therefore
>   might never return. Use the
>   TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock method to
>   block for a specified interval, and
>   then return if the calling thread has
>   not entered upgradeable mode during
>   that interval.